# htaccess block *bot and bot*

Tags: .htaccess, block, bots

I'm having trouble blocking two bad bots that keep sucking bandwidth from my site and I'm certain it has something to do with the * in the user-agent name that they use.

Right now, I'm using the following code to block the bad bots (this is an excerpt)...

```
# block bad bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^spider$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^robot$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^crawl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^discovery$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

When I try to do `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^*bot$ [OR]` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(*bot)$ [OR]` I get an error.

Guessing there is a pretty easy way to do this that I just haven't found yet on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asterisk (*) in a regular expression pattern needs to be escaped, since it is being interpreted as part of the regular expression.
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^\*bot$`
should do the trick.

Comment: Doh - I didn't preview properly.  My backslash was not showing up and needed to be escaped.  Ironic, eh.

Comment: I try with MsnBot and it was not working for me.
It was only working for GoogleBot. I use : RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^\*bot$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

Comment: @NileshKumar This expression should match any User-Agent ending in "bot". Check what User-Agent MsnBot is sending, and if it is different you should probably submit a new question describing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing a dot `.`, change your condition to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*bot$ [OR]
```

Comment: You mean it is causing Apache 500? Can you pls tell me what error it is writing in he logs?

Answer (score 0):

But how is this going to prevent Bad Bot access?

I work for a security company (also PM at [Botopedia.org](http://www.botopedia.org)) and I can tell that 99.9% of bad bots will not use any of these expressions in their user-agent string.

Most of the time Bad Bots will use legitimate looking user-agents (impersonating browsers and VIP bots like Googlebot) and you simply cannot filter them via user-agent data alone.

For effective bot detection you should look into other signs like:

1) Suspicious signatures (i.e. Order of Header parameter)

or/and

2) Suspicious behavior (i.e. early robots.txt access or request rates/patterns)

Then you should use different challenges (i.e. JS or Cookie or even CAPTCHA) to verify your suspicions.

The problem you've described is often referred to as a "Parasitic Drag".

This is a very real and serious issue and we actually published a research about it just a couple of month ago.

(We found that on an average sized site 51% of visitors will be bots, 31% malicious)

Honestly, I don't think you can solve this problem with several line of RegEx.

We offer our Bot filtering services for free and there are several others like us. (I can endorse good services if needed)

GL.

Comment: Also this might be useful: 
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/how-can-i-identify-that-my-page-is-requested-by-robot-but-not-users-browser/17365#17365

Comment: Kudos for working for a security company, but your company has no clue what bad bots are hitting my site and what user agent strings those bots are using.  Appreciate your effort here, but your response doesn't have anything to do with resolving my question and seems more like a spammed sales pitch than trying to help me with what I need.